# Swift2 check array in dictionary

Tags: arrays, swift, swift2, nsarray

I am trying to create case in one line but I can not find how can I do that

I need to write that code in one line

```
     if let holdings = i["holdings"] as Array where !holdings.isEmpty {
```

any ideas?

Comment: Why do you need to write this in one line?

Comment: because I have "if ... else if .. else"

Comment: An array of what?

Comment: Try to avoid using `Array`, use `[AnyObject]` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AnyObject since your didn't specify what was inside your array.

```
if let holdings = i["key"] as? [AnyObject] where !holdings.isEmpty
```

or

```
if let holdings = i["key"] as? Array<AnyObject> where !holdings.isEmpty
```

Comment: Try to avoid using `Array<YourObject>`, use `[YourObject]` instead.